# scope identity in stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have got the following stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.insert_movie

(
@first_name varchar(50),
@movie_name varchar(50),
@date date,
@last_id_inserted int,
@last_name varchar(50)
)

AS
INSERT INTO movies (movie_name,movie_date) VALUES (@movie_name,@date);

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS scope;

INSERT INTO customer (first_name,last_name,movie_id) 
    VALUES (@first_name,@last_name,@last_id_inserted)
```

I want to insert the scope variable into @last_id_inserted.

Basically, I want to insert the last inserted id (movie_id) to the customer table..

not sure about the syntax though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign the result of the function to the variable.

```
SET @last_id_inserted = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

There is no need to have `@last_id_inserted` as a parameter. Declare it as a variable in the SP.

```
DECLARE @last_id_inserted int;
SET @last_id_inserted = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Or you can use it directly in the insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO customer (first_name,last_name,movie_id) 
    VALUES (@first_name,@last_name,SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT @last_id_inserted = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
or
SET @last_id_inserted = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variable in the stored procedure and assign the value of the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` function:

```
DECLARE @last_id_inserted int;    
SET @last_id_inserted = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: hmm..is that it..do I have other syntax errors?!? can I execute one statement after another like that?!?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Yes, this should do it. Why, are you getting some other error?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to other answers that you can add `OUTPUT` clause (SQLServer 2005 and higher) to your `INSERT` instead of using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`