# T-Sql: How to write a SP that executes several similar insert statement?

Tags: t-sql

I have this table called **DevProject** which keeps track of developers who are affected to a particular project.

```
ID           int PK
DevID        int NOT NULL FK
ProjectID    int NOT NULL FK
```

ID is the PK column for DevProject table. DevID and ProjectID are respectively PK in the Developers and Project tables. When A new project starts, a group of developers are affected to that project. Some of the developers might still be working on other projects. So, After the manager has decide whose going to work on a particular new project, the **DevProject** table should be populate with the ID of the new project and the ID of the developer.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: A many to many table.  Would not have an ID.  Have a composite PK of DevID and ProjecID.

Comment: Is the key in Developers and Project tables an Identity?

Comment: yes they are both identities. Once the manager select developers for project, it the ID of the developers' table will be known.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637834/scope-identity-in-stored-procedure

Comment: @Blam, I'm sorry, maybe I was not that explicit. retrieving the ID of the last project inserted is just part of the problem. What I want is, after retrieving that new project ID, to be able to write a SP that will take care of that, given that we know already all the developers ID. Just a repetitive routine that'll help to keep hitting the DB for such a small amount of data.

Comment: Exactly you retrieve the Id via scope_identity in a varialble and then use it in the multiple insert for the project members.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you meant.  And that link had the answer.

```
  declare @ID int;
  insert into table_1 (value) values ('newProj2');
  SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  insert into table_2 (id, memberID) values (@ID, 1);
  insert into table_2 (id, memberID) values (@ID, 2);
```